# Create OpsWorks stack on deploy an app

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-opsworks

When I deploy an application I'd like to create an OpsWorks stack.
E.g.: I deploy git branch feature/XXX-001 and stack XXX-001 will being created.
Which services should I use for this point?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AWS code deploy. https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

You don’t create a new stack but add a new application version which is then deployed to your existing beanstalk stack